# Understanding the proof of how "only vector fields that are independent of path are conservative"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

In James Stewart's Multivariable Calculus: Concepts and Contexts, this theorem is stated:

"Suppose $\mathbf{\vec F}$ is a vector field that is continuous on an open connected region $\mathit{D}$. If $\int_C \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}$ is independent of path in $\mathit{D}$, then $\mathbf{\vec F}$ is a conservative vector field on $\mathit{D}$; that is, there exists a function $\mathit{f}$ such that $\nabla \mathit{f} = \mathbf{\vec F}$."

The proof is as follows:

"Let $\mathit{A(a,b)}$ be a fixed point in $\mathit{D}$. We construct the desired potential function $\mathit{f}$ by defining $$ \mathit{f\,(x,y)} = \int_\mathit{(a,b)}^\mathit{(x,y)} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}$$ for any point in $\mathit{(x,y)}$ in $\mathit{D}$. Since $\int_C \mathbf{\vec F}\,d\mathbf{\vec r}$ is independent of path, it does not matter which path $\mathit{C}$ from $\mathit{(a,b)}$ to $\mathit{(x,y)}$ is used to evaluate $\mathit{f\,(x,y)}$. Since $\mathit{D}$ is open, there exists a disk contained in $\mathit{D}$ with center $\mathit{(x,y)}$. Choose any point $\mathit{(x_1,y)}$ in the disk with $\mathit{x_1 \lt x}$ and let $\mathit{C}$ consist of any path $\mathit{C_1}$ from $\mathit{(a,b)}$ to $\mathit{(x_1,y)}$ followed by the horizontal line segment $\mathit{C_2}$ from $\mathit{(x_1,y)}$ to $\mathit{(x,y)}$. Then $$ \mathit{f\,(x,y)} = \int_\mathit{C_1} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}\, + \int_\mathit{C_2} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r} = \int_\mathit{(a,b)}^\mathit{(x_1,y)} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}\, + \int_\mathit{C_2} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}$$ Notice that the first of these integrals does not depend on $\mathit{x}$, so $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\;\mathit{f\,(x,y)} = 0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_\mathit{C_2} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}$$ If we write $\mathbf{\vec F} = \mathit{P}\,\mathbf{\vec i} + \mathit{Q}\,\mathbf{\vec j}$, then $$ \int_\mathit{C_2} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r} = \int_\mathit{C_2} P\,dx + Q\,dy$$ On $\mathit{C_2}$, $y$ is constant, so $dy = 0$. Using $t$ as the parameter, where $x_1 \leqslant t \leqslant x$, we have $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\;\mathit{f\,(x,y)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_\mathit{C_2} P\,dx + Q\,dy = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_\mathit{x_1}^x P(t,y)\,dt = P(x,y)$$ by Part 1 of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus."

A similar process of deriving $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \;\mathit{f\,(x,y)}$ is used to show that $\mathbf{\vec F} = \mathit{P}\,\mathbf{\vec i} + \mathit{Q}\,\mathbf{\vec j} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\;\mathbf{\vec i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\;\mathbf{\vec j} = \nabla f$.

I have two questions:

How is $\int_\mathit{(a,b)}^\mathit{(x_1,y)} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r}$ not dependent on $x$?

How does writing $\mathbf{\vec F} = \mathit{P}\,\mathbf{\vec i} + \mathit{Q}\,\mathbf{\vec j}$ show $ \int_\mathit{C_2} \mathbf{\vec F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec r} = \int_\mathit{C_2} P\,dx + Q\,dy$?

Thank you so much for reading through the long post, and apologies in advance for poor formatting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, the value of the integral is, by definition, $f(x_1,y)$, where $x_1$ is a constant).

For the second question, you need to work out what $\int_C {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf r}$ means.

Suppose ${\bf F} = P \, {\bf i} + Q \, {\bf j}$.  Suppose we had a parametrization $x = x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, $a \leq t \leq b$ of $C$ so that ${\bf r}(t) = x(t) \, {\bf i} + y(t) \, {\bf j}$ is a vector-valued function that traces out the curve $C$.

Write out the integral.  Then write out what you would get if you used the same parametrization and tried to setup $\int_C P \, dx + Q \, dx$.  You will see that both integrals are equal to the following:

$$\int_a^b \left( P(x(t),y(t)) x'(t) + Q(x(t),y(t)) y'(t) \right) \, dt$$.